# Does COPADO provide free trial period for accessing COPADO Robotic testing platform?

Tags: automation-testing

I am looking for doing test automation of web application using COPADO Robotic testing platform. But, not sure whether they are offering free trial period or not ?

If anyone is aware about free trial, can you please explain the process to be followed to access free trial of COPADO Robotic testing platform ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, but you would need to [contact the sales team](https://www.copado.com/demo).